# Center image on page HTML and CSS

Tags: image, center, positioning, sizing

I created a landing page for the website www.foscaintepidario.it
But I want the image on it to be centered, and remain centered, also when the browser-view is changed. Changed in the perspective of size, but also the switch from landscape to portrait and the other way around.
In het HTML/CSS I currently make a distinction between the portrait and landscape version, they both have their own image.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: You need to show us what have you tried in order to fix this problem. You can't expect us to post a full answer from scratch.

Comment: I already tried differnet solutions in a table, also with a background, but nothing fits....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use css background elements to have a clean view.

```
background-image: url(url to image);
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: I implemented this solution earlier, but the image remains in the top-area, and I can see only half of it.

Comment: I recreated that solution, so perhaps that will be helpfull.
please see this link: http://www.foscaintepidario.it/index-background.html

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. The solution with the background-image works fine. The only thing I had to add was the height: 100vh parameter!

Thnx for your support